# regex - dont want to tokenize certain part of the input

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have to tokenize string where the string does not contain any word character and if that is "*". But I cannot tokenize two words i.e. "START_CALL" and "END_CALL" which has "*".

So far I came up with :

```
split_tokens = re.split(r'([\W_])', string_to_be_replaced)
```

But it is splitting all tokens with underscore(`_`) and splitting "START", "_", "CALL".

I can split on "START_CALL" and then do the split tokens in the sub-strings.

But would be interested to know is there a much elegant way for doing this?

Comment: Should you split *other* words with an underscore in the middle, at the underscore?

Comment: Please clarify (if the solution in my answer does not work for you): do you want  to only avoid matching `_` in between *letters*, or any *word* chars?

Comment: I want to apply just for "START_CALL" and "END_CALL" tokens.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
(\W|_\b|\b_)
([\W_])(?<!\B_\B)
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/lMrtxI/1) / [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/lMrtxI/2). Details:

- `(` - start of a capturing group

  - `\W|` - any non-word char (a char other than letter, digit, some connector punctuation and most diacritic chars), or
  - `_\b|` - an underscore that is not followed with a word char, or
  - `\b_` - an underscore that is not preceded with a word char
- `)` - end of the group.
- `[\W_](?<!\B_\B)` - any non-word char or `_` that is not a `_` both preceded and followed with word chars.